# XML Validation avoiding hell implementation

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, .net-4.5

I am very unfortunate to have crossed paths with XML and need to validate XML data based on rules, that are currently held in XSD.

The problem is that the XML for the same DOC has 3 versions, and each version has separate rules and sub rules based on values of elements.

I was wondering if there is any `nuget package thing` created in the last years that can validate XML, with a nicer engine, syntax or something to avoid using the build in, old and inflexible .NET junk.

One way I know is to parse the XML, check the values, eg version, then use and XSD for that version of the file. But some rules apply to the same elements across versions, ie Male/Female type questions. SO technically I will have to start with 9 XSD files and land up with lots more as the rules get complex. All rules on all version are in use, making it even more complicated.

I have seen something bounce off my screen with assert.. but .NET does not support that. Is there some kind of validation engine and syntax. I really just want 1 File to apply rules based on the data that the XML holds.

Comment: Look into using [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/), which can meet your goal of having a single file of rules and be able to apply assertions that depend upon data values found in the XML being validated.

Comment: Thanks for that. I came across it but wasnt sure what the heck to do with it. So this time I browsed the site more and tried to find some link to .NET, and I did, after reading really carefully. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, THANKS @kjhughes! Tthat is what I saw, Schematron "assert" but I thought it was only for like Perl only. But investigated it further and found [Schematron.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetopensrc/files/Schematron.NET/)

Download the file, it has a basic win forms validator or just open the DLL project on its own, check out the source and compile the DLL.

Then in the schema you declare it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/po-schematron" xmlns="http://example.com/po-schematron" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <schema xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
```

and then you just need to spend some time and read the [Schematron ISO](http://www.schematron.com/iso/dsdl-3-fdis.pdf) and get on with validating XML.. even though you know you don't really want to.. but sometimes you just have to.

### [Hers is an introduction to Shematron if you never used it or know very little about XPath. It has some sample code and a good enough walkthrough of the whole thing.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468554.aspx)